# How to associate a script at boot time to a specific run level?

Tags: ubuntu, startup, upstart, runlevel

I am trying to understand how run levels work. I understand the meaning of the 7 run levels and I understand that they were usually configured by `/etc/inittab`, which used to call `/etc/init.d/rc`, which itself called the various scripts to configure the different run levels and how they should behave.

Right now I am on an Ubuntu Server machine (12.04) and I see that the `inittab` file is not used anymore and that instead, scripts are found in the `/etc/init` directory.

Now suppose that I want to execute a script at boot time (for example to launch an application). Usually I would do this editing the `/etc/init.d/rc.local` file.

And here comes my question: if I edit this file, will this script run for **every** run level?

If I want the script to work only at run level 5 for example, should I put this script into the `/etc/rc5.d/` folder instead? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so this is what I found out:

The latest Ubuntu versions make use of upstart (as @polemon correctly pointed out), which uses specific config files in the `/etc/init` directory to configure the run level at which a script should run.
Upstart puts upstart job files in the `/etc/init` folder and normal init scripts in `/etc/init.d` and in the various `/etc/rc*.d` folders and is actually able to run both of them.

Systems not using upstart only use `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/rc*.d`. In this case, runlevels are set adding a symlink to the script in the appropriate `/etc/rc*.d` folder.

Also, apparently `rc.local` runs the scripts at multiuser runlevel.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu, this is called [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/). I suggest you read the [Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#runlevels), it discusses how to create scripts to run at a specific (pseudo) runlevel.

What you're refering to, is the "System V" init system. The idea is to have things started concurrently. I suggest you take a look at the [`instance`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#instance) functionality of Upstart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are there other distros that still use run levels though? In this case, how would this work?

Comment: @user1301428 well, that's almost a philosophical question. the *BSDs still adhere firmly to the "System", as they're more direct descendants of the UNIX from AT&T. Fedora still uses init-rc quite extensively, and I still make init scripts. Ubuntu tries to streamline the boot process, to make booting quicker, etc. hence, Upstart.

Comment: Ok I see. Both with System and Upstart though, is editing the `rc.local` file still the best way to do this?

Comment: @user1301428 I can't say that. It depends on what you want to do. if it is some server you're managing, probably not. If it's logging or "householding", probably yes. If it is something periodically happening, maybe `crontab` is the better solution. Identifying what's best for you, is yours to decide.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup <-- that's probably relevant, to you. `rc.local` is actually ran by Upstart once in the boot process (I'm not exactly sure when, though).

Comment: If I understand this correctly, upstart uses upstart jobs in the `etc/init` folder and init scripts in `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/rc*.d` folders, so apparently at the moment you can still do this in several ways. I just wonder what level `rc.local` is actually run at if I don't specify a level and if I haven't set the default level in `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`

Comment: Yes, although I can't guarantee it's gonna work without problems, just run a few tests, if you definitely decide on using `rc.local` I cannot tell you at which level `rc.local` runs, since my systems never use it. But finding out yourself is easy: `runlevel > /root/level.txt`